# How can I restrict the input char value?

Tags: java, switch-statement, calculator

I created simple calculator using switch case. When I enter the invalid operators, but it takes that value .And at last it gives the default switch case .How can I restrict it.

```
package calculator;
```

import java.util.*;
public class Calculator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    char operator;
    Double num1, num2, result;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter the operator: +,-,*,/,% ");
    operator = input.next().charAt(0);
    
    //user input
    
    System.out.println("Enter the First Number:");
    num1 = input.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the Second Number:");
    num2 = input.nextDouble();
    

    switch (operator) {
        case '+': 
            result = num1+num2;
            System.out.println(num1+" + "+num1+" = " + result);
            break;
        case '-': 
            result = num1-num2;
            System.out.println(num1+" - "+num1+" = " + result);
            break;
        case '*': 
            result = num1*num2;
            System.out.println(num1+" * "+num1+" = " + result);
            break;
        case '/': 
            result = num1/num2;
            System.out.println(num1+" / "+num1+" = " + result);
            break;
        case '%': 
            result = num1%num2;
            System.out.println(num1+" % "+num1+" = " + result);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid operator");
        break;
    }
    input.close();

    
    
}
```

}

console output
Enter the operator: +,-,*,/,%
7
Enter the First Number:
5
Enter the Second Number:
5
Invalid operator

Comment: You can't. You can only loop until the user gives valid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Character.isDigit(c)){
   // what you want for true
}
else{
   // what you want for false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.
Java or any other programming languages run code sequentially.
Here once the operator is entered you can check to proceed further for other statements.
The logic of code how you write, that way it is executed.

So in this case, once you take value for operator check whether that operator is allowed in your case or not.
If allowed then run the further code else not run that.